# How to filter data in ng-repeat using a jquery slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs, rangeslider

I am using [Ion.RangeSlider](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/demo_interactions.html) that is a jquery slider.
I have json data that is coming through http and i am displaying it in the page using ng-repeat directive.
I want to filter the JSON data using this slider that looks like below

[image]

under the image you can see two values **185;500** that is the value i am getting when i bind ng-model to the slider.

so, my questions is how do i filter my data using this **slider**?

**EDIT**
I changed the Slider that i was using and made the same CSS changes to make it look like the above slider.
https://github.com/rzajac/angularjs-slider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do that with `ng-repeat` and a custom filter. Just use your binded value and replace them as `min` and `max` in `myfilter` like:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | myfilter: { min: slider.min, max: slider.max }">
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/vhpLpcj3/1)

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="dummy">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items | myfilter: { min: 185, max: 500 }">
        <p>{{item.name}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller('dummy', function($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.items = [{name: 'hello', cost: 100}, {name: 'world', cost: 200}]
});
app.filter('myfilter', function() {
   return function( items, condition) {
    var filtered = [];

    if(condition === undefined || condition === ''){
      return items;
    }

    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {          
       if(item.cost >= condition.min && item.cost <= condition.max){
         filtered.push(item);
       }
    });

    return filtered;
  };
});
```